# Java regex possesive quantifiers

Tags: java, regex, quantifiers

Given this regex:

```
x[^x]*+x
```

and this input string for matching:

```
xbbbx
```

The result is the matched text `xbbbx` starting at index 0 and ending at index 5.

But, by only changing the last letter `x` to `Z` in both the regex and the string, we get this regex:

```
x[^x]*+Z
```

and this input string:

```
xbbbZ
```

and the result is: *no match found*.

Why would a change in a single letter produce this change in behavior?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why is you are using the "possessive" quantifier which will match the symbol as much as it can.

So in this case with `xbbbZ` the regex `x[^x]*+` matches all non x characters until the end of the line, where it stops.  It has already consumed the "Z" inside of the input `xbbbZ`.

This regex, `x[^x]*+x`, works with `xbbbx` because the "possessive" quantifier **has** to stop when it reaches an `x`.  Your input has an `x` at the end, and therefore the possessive quantifier stops.  This allows the last part of the regex `x` to be matched with `x`.

At the end of the Java [tutorial page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html), you can see another example of the possessive quantifier.